# MVC Viewbag passing list to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

sWhat is wrong with this code? I'm just trying to practice passing a list to my view:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult About()

    {
        List<string> ListofColors = new List<string>();
        ViewBag.colors.Add("red");
        ViewBag.colors.Add("green");
        ViewBag.colors.Add("blue");

        ViewBag.ListColors = ListofColors;
        return View();
```

View:

```
<ul id="colors">

@foreach (var colors in (List<string>) ViewBag.ListColors) { 
<li>
    @colors
</li>
} 

</ul>
```

The error I get is:CS0103: The name 'colors' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I don't see where you add `colors` to the ViewBag

Comment: @CAbbott I did this: ViewBag.colors.Add("red");
            ViewBag.colors.Add("green");
            ViewBag.colors.Add("blue");

Comment: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: What you did was not correct. You should look at `Plan B`s answer to see what/where you need to add code.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing the `ListColors` object in to your viewbag, in the controller action:

```
 ....
 ViewBag.ListColors = ListofColors;
 return View();
 ....
```

Comment: @Batsu glad to help -- easy to overlook these things; as a suggestion, to make things even more streamlined, I suggest using a view model so you can leverage type safety and intellisense in your view!

Answer (score 1):

The line is missing in your controller code.

```
ViewBag.ListColors = colors;
```

Edit :: The code should be like below in your controller

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    List<string> ListofColors = new List<string>();
    ListofColors.Add("red");
    ListofColors.Add("green");
    ListofColors.Add("blue");

    ViewBag.ListColors = ListofColors;
    return View();
}
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Now is says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> ListofColors = new List<string>();
ListofColors.Add("red");
ListofColors.Add("green");
ListofColors.Add("blue");

ViewBag.ListColors = ListofColors;
```

Add Colors To Your List and pass listofcolors to viewbag